# What is the significance of configuration.svc and configuration91.svc files when adding a service reference (WSDL)?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl, .net-4.5

When we generate a WSDL, there are multiple files along which what interests me is `configuration.svc` and `configuration91.svc` ?

Why there are two files generated ? And why are they being named as `91` at end ?

Comment: Wondered this myself too. This question is top answer on Google when mentioning `configuration91.svc`